# Cancel and wait on async Task methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

Trying to figure this out but can't find anything definitive.

Suppose I have a class that does some work async and can be started or stopped on the fly:

```
class ModelObject
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private CancellationToken ct;
    private Progress<int> progress;
    
    private async Task DoSomething(IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        ...
        
        while (DoingSomething)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10000); // Take our sweet time to cancel
                // Cancel work and return
            }
            
            ...
        }       
    }
    
    public async void StartAsync()
    {
        progress = new Progress<int>(...);
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        ct = cts.Token;
        
        await DoSomething(progress);
    }
    
    public void Stop()
    {
        ct.Cancel();
        
        // HELP: await while DoSomething cancels
        
        // perform cleanup
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to `await` while the **existing instance** of `DoSomething` cancels.

Typical use would be like this:

```
ModelObject modelObject = new ModelObject();
modelObject.StartAsync();
modelObject.Stop();
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just a small note: `async void` is bad. It should be `async Task`.

Comment: A [mcve] would be great here. It's hard to tell what you're cleaning up so it's hard to offer a solution.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hi made a small change hopefully this might help. Cleaning up as in deleting files being worked on etc.

Comment: Did you read the [mcve] page? You certainly haven't provided anything of the sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference would be to add a `Completion` property to the `ModelObject` class. The caller could choose to `await` or not the `Completion` after canceling an operation. Also I would probably place guards against an improper use of the API. Attempting to start a new operation while an existing one is pending, would cause an exception.

```
public Task Completion { get; private set; } = Task.CompletedTask;

public async void Start()
{
    if (_cts != null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Operation is in progress.");
    using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        _ct = _cts.Token;
        _progress = new Progress<int>(/*...*/);
        this.Completion = DoSomethingAsync();
        try
        {
            await this.Completion;
        }
        catch { } // Ignore
        finally
        {
            _cts = null;
            _ct = default;
            _progress = null;
        }
    }
}

public void Stop()
{
    _cts?.Cancel();
}
```

Another piece of advice: in case of cancellation ensure that your `DoSomethingAsync` throws an `OperationCanceledException`. This is the [expected behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) of a cancelable asynchronous operation. For example if you pass the token to any built-in API, you'll notice that the returned task will complete as `Canceled` immediately after calling the `_cts.Cancel()` method. To mimic this behavior you could call `_ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` inside the loop, and pass the token to any API that accepts it (for example the `Task.Delay` method). In fact it would be probably better to catch internally this exception, and do the clean up inside the catch block:

```
private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    try
    {
        while (doingSomething)
        {
            // Do some work
            _ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000); // Take our sweet time to cancel
        throw; // Rethrow the exception
    }
    finally
    {
        // perform cleanup, whether successful, failed or canceled
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The reason I'm performing the cleanup in the `Stop()` method is because I want to be able to vary the cleanup e.g. different cleanups for `Stop()` or `Cancel()` or `Pause()` or something else. I was aiming to make the `DoSomething` `Task` only concern itself with the actual task and not deal with cleanups.

Also, the `Start()` method should only be concerned with starting the `Task`.

Comment: @antikbd in my example the `Start` is `async void`, so from the caller's perspective it does nothing more than starting the task. The fact that it also attaches a continuation to the task, in order to update the internal state of the class when the task completes, is transparent to the caller. Regarding having different cleanups for different flavors of `Stop`, you could have different CTS for each `Stop`, or have some extra state like: `public void Stop1() { _stopType = 1; _cts?.Cancel(); }`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's my current approach - using multiple `CancellationToken`s. However, I wish I didn't have to check for multiple `Token`s (due to the chance of bugs) and could just use one `Token` and multiple methods.

Comment: @antikbd having different methods that all attempt to mutate the internal state, hoping that the caller will not call them at the wrong time or multiple times or in incorrect order, seems more error-prone to me!

Answer (score 2):

While you could await the task returned from `DoSomething`, you can also use a `TaskCompletionSource`;

```
        private TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs;

        private async Task DoSomething(IProgress<int> progress){
          ...
           while (DoingSomething)
           {
               if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
               {
                   // Cancel work and return
               } 
            ...
           }       
           tcs.SetResult(null);
        }

        public async Task Stop () {
           cts.Cancel();
           await tcs.Task;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why `StartAsync` method is async since it indefinitely executes unless the `Stop` is Invoked. I mean it will not return at some point in time without another action. I feel there is no need for `async` in this class
But if it necessary, I've drafted code that might help

```
    class ModelObject {
        private CancellationTokenSource cts;
        private CancellationToken ct;
        private Progress<int> progress;
        private Task doSomethingTask;
        private async Task DoSomething(IProgress<int> progress){
          ...
           while (DoingSomething)
           {
               if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
               {
                   // Cancel work and return
               } 
            ...
           }       
        }

        public async void StartAsync () {
            progress = new Progress<int>(...);
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource ();
            ct = cts.Token;
            doSomethingTask = DoSomething (progress);
            await doSomethingTask;
        }

        public void Stop () {
            cts.Cancel();
            doSomethingTask.Wait();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If answer would not suggest to use `.Wait` it would be actually complete solution...